# Using str2func with multiple strings that represent anonymous functions

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

So this is what i started doing first:

```
simple1 = @(x)x
simple2 = @(x)x
simple3 = @(x)x

SUM = @(x)(simple1(x) + simple2(x) + simple3(x))

str2func(SUM)
```

i get:

```
Undefined function 'str2func' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
```

i also tried this:

```
simple1 = @(x)x
simple2 = @(x)x
simple3 = @(x)x

SUM = @(x)(func2str(simple1(x)) + func2str(simple2(x)) + func2str(simple3(x)))

SUM(1)
```

i created 3 anonymous functions with a simple argument etc.. what i want to do is to create another anonymous function(SUM) that represents the SUM of the other three anonymous functions. Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. `str2func(SUM)` doesn't make sense because `SUM` is a function handle, which is what the error message is telling you. Did you mean `func2str(SUM)`? `SUM = @(x)(simple1(x) + simple2(x) + simple3(x))` already does what you ask for and it's not clear why you want strings anywhere. I recommend reading the documentation.

Comment: "Any ideas on what im doing wrong?" Yes, you're using `str2func` unnecessarily. You've already composed the three functions into a new one in your first code snippet, now just use the new function. If I do `SUM(1)` instead of `str2func(SUM)` I get `3`.

Comment: I am making this code for an exercise that we have in school. Says we have to use str2func. Any tops on how to establish that? @beaker

Comment: I'm not sure what precisely you're trying to achieve, but if you need to use `str2func`, you'll need to pass it a character array rather than a function handle.